# how do you assign cell voltage to BatteryState

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to send cell voltage information using ROS on an arduino, but I get an empty array as output. Do I need to set the size of the array somehow?

**edited** added voltage length and pointer to array of cell voltages, now the example works as expected

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/BatteryState.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

sensor_msgs::BatteryState battery_state;

int number_of_cells = 2;
float cell_1_voltage = 12.2;
float cell_2_voltage = 12.3;
float * cell_voltage = new float[number_of_cells]

ros::Publisher battery_state_publisher("battery_state", &battery_state);

void setup()
{
   nh.initNode();
   nh.advertise(battery_state_publisher);

   battery_state.cell_voltage_length = number_of_cells;
}

void loop()
{
   cell_voltage[0] = cell_1_voltage;
   cell_voltage[1] = cell_2_voltage;

   battery_state.cell_voltage = cell_voltage;

   battery_state_publisher.publish(&battery_state);
   nh.spinOnce();
}
```

http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/BatteryState.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281169/how-do-you-assign-cell-voltage-to-batterystate/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Do I need to set the size of the array somehow?

Yes. See [wiki/rosserial/Overview/Limitations - Arrays](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations#Arrays):

> to send an array message, we have to set the length and pointer. [..]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1